# Laplace transform of a random variable: Inversion formula from an interval

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with a CDF $F$.  Let $L_X(t)$ denote the Laplace transform of $F$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
L_X(t)=E[ e^{-tX}], \quad t \ge 0 
\end{align}

It is known that $L_X(t)$ is unique for every open interval.

Therefore, if $L_X(t)$ is known on an interval $(t_0, t_1)$, there must exist an inversion formula from  $L_X(t)$ to  $F$.

**My Question:** Given that we know $L_X(t)$ **only** on $(t_0, t_1)$ what is the inversion formula back to $F$?

I want to point out the if $L_X(t)$ is known  for all $t \ge 0$, then the inversion formula is given by 
\begin{align}
\sum_{ n \le t x} \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} L_X^{(n)}(t) \to F(x) \text{ as }  t \to \infty  \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where $x$ is a point of continuity of $F$  and  $L_X^{(n)}$ is $n$-th derivative.

This question was moved here from [mathStackExhange](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3407452/edit)

Comment: It is analytic in $\Re(t)$ thus once you know it on $(t_0,t_1)$ you know it on $\Re(t) > 0$ and the inversion formula is from the contour integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform your inversion formula is wrong $\lim_{t \to \infty}\sum_{n \le tx} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} L_X^{(n)}(t) =\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{n \le tx} \int_0^\infty \frac{y^n}{n!} e^{-ty}F(y)dy\le \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_0^\infty e^{(1-t)y} F(y)dy = 0 $

Comment: @reuns Note that I have $(-t)^n$ and not $(-1)^n$.   I would have to think about the first part of your comment about the inversion.

Comment: @reuns Question? Would the inversion formula you suggest produce pdf or cdf? I think it would produce pdf.

Comment: If you know that $L_X(t)$ converges on $(t_0, t_1)$, then it converges on all of $(t_0, \infty)$. Moreover, if $t, \delta > 0$ are chosen so that $t_0 < t-\delta < t < t_1$, then for any integer $k\geq 1$ we have $$\sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n_1}}{n_1!}\cdots\sum_{n_k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^{n_k}}{n_k!}L_X^{(n_1+\cdots+n_k)}(t) = L_X(t+k\delta). $$ So, at least theoretically, we can recover values of $L_X$ only using those on $(t_0, t_1)$. (*Remark.* The above iterated summations cannot be reduced to multiple summation in general.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. Could you explain how you prove the formula? Maybe you can put it as an answer.

Comment: @Boby, This is basically the Taylor series. If you know that $L_X$ converges on $(t_0, t_1)$ and $t \in(t_0, t_1)$, then using the Fubini's Theorem, we can check that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^n}{n!}L_X^{(n)}(t)=L_X(t+s)$$ holds for all $s$ with $|s|<t-t_0$. So if $t$ is chosen close to $t_1$, this allows to 'reveal' the values of $L_X$ on a larger interval, and this procedure can be repeated.